# Can't debug to fix virtual host issue on windows 10

Tags: apache, google-chrome, firefox, windows-10

I have problem when i try to setup virtual host on my windows 10 pc.
In my hosts file:

`127.0.0.1  project.dev`

In my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@project.dev
    DocumentRoot "path to project"
    ServerName project.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/project.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project.dev-error-access.log" common
    <Directory path to project>
        Require all granted
        Allowoverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.exe run without error.
I try to run:
`localhost`
It works but when i try to run:
`project.dev`
in the browser, it does not work.

```
This site can’t be reached
project.dev refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have tried to solve this issue for hours but i can't.
Windows firewall logs, System logs, Applications logs, Apache logs don't show me any infos to help me.

Could anyone help me debug this issue?

Thanks!

------------UPDATE--------

Today, i updated php and apache to newer version

`https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.2.6-Win32-VC15-x64.zip
https://www.apachehaus.com/downloads/httpd-2.4.33-o110h-x64-vc14-r2.zip`

and tried to run project.dev with simple vhost:

        `<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:/Users/0x1111/workspace"
        ServerName project.dev
        #ServerName www.example.com:80
        </VirtualHost>`

Chrome shows https error:

`Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from project.dev (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Running `localhost` it works normal.

----UPDATE -----

when i use nslookup `localhost`:

`Server:  resolver1-fs.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.123
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    localhost
Addresses:  ::1
          127.0.0.1`

But when i nslookup `project.dev`:

`Server:  resolver1-fs.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.123
*** resolver1-fs.opendns.com can't find project.dev: Non-existent domain`